# React App displaying error for http request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, web, web-applications

I deployed my react app with nodejs in https://learnhosting.herokuapp.com, its working well, apis(express) are also working properly.

But while accessing the site with [learnhosting.herokuapp.com](http://learnhosting.herokuapp.com) pages other than homepage not working i.e cannot GET /url. Also when opening this in mobile all pages except homepage showing cannot GET /url error for even https://learnhosting.herokuapp.com, how to fix this error?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To have routing working properly on page load you must configure the front-end service (Apache/nginx... or also node if it run on port 80) to serve your index page for every request.
Don't know if this is doable on herokuapp.

Comment: How to do that in react

Comment: This has nothing to do with React. Search how to deploy a webserver like nginx on herokuapp